# Get textarea character count using reactjs with help of usestate hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs i have tried to get textarea character count, It's need to display while user typing in textarea but not able to get count also throw state object is readonly error. My code is

```
import React from "react";

export default function FullWidthTabs() {
  const [textAreaCount = 0, textAreaTotal = 250] = React.useState(0);

  const recalculate = e => {
    console.log("event value:", e);
    textAreaCount = e.target.value.length;
  };
  return (
    <textarea
      type="text"
      rows={5}
      className="full_height_Width"
      onChange={recalculate}
    />
  );
}
```

Here expected output need to update character count like 
[image: example]

Comment: `const [textAreaCount = 0, textAreaTotal = 250] = React.useState(0);` that's not how you are supposed to use state. I'd suggest you to refer the documentation to better understand how the state hook works. Or if you can create [mcve] I can help with that.

Comment: This textarea i need to use under material UI tabs Here UI tabs wrote useState() hook in reactjs

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        rows={5}
        className="full_height_Width"
        onChange={e => setCount(e.target.value.length)}
      />
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-swanson-ux11q)

Comment: Here i had problem error throws setCount not defined

Comment: const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0); This statement is array destructuring. If you access setCount, it will definitely work. Check the codesandbox link.

Answer (score 3):

Here is working code. Update the usage of `useState`.

```
import React from "react";

export default function FullWidthTabs() {
  const [textAreaCount, setTextAreaCount] = React.useState(0);

  const recalculate = e => {
    console.log("event value:", e);
    setTextAreaCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p> {`Textarea Char Count: ${textAreaCount}`} </p>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        rows={5}
        className="full_height_Width"
        onChange={recalculate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should consider that you can't change state value directly by assigning a value to it.
Secondly you should use useState hook like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Here *count* is your state and *setCount* is a function that change (set) state.
So your recalculate function must change to:

```
const recalculate = (e) => {
        console.log('event value:', e);
        setCount(e.target.value.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the code you want

https://codesandbox.io/s/rkv88-lsyvo

usestate hook   has two parameters  the first is the name of the var you want & the second is a function that you pass value to  it  to change the variable

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost correct, but you have 2 mistakes here

1. inside recalculate function you should declare the textAreaCount with `let` keyword.
2. the `useState` hook is not used correctly.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function FullWidthTabs() {

const [textAreaCount, settextAreaCount] = React.useState(0);

const recalculate = (e) => {
    let textAreaCount = e.target.value.length;
    console.log(textAreaCount);
}

return(
    <textarea type="text" rows={5} className="full_height_Width"
                                        onChange={recalculate} />
    );
}
```

Comment: you should use `settextAreaCount(e.target.value.length)` on line 8.

Comment: You have mistakes in your code, but you are telling the OP they have mistakes...