# How to create a character counter in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants, charactercount

I am new and creating something with react for the first time. i want to create a character counter in a textarea in react. The counter should have a maximum length of 800 characters. i created this code, but i don't know how to include const without getting an error message.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Component } from 'react';

function Counter() {
    return (
      
const rezensionTextArea = document.getElementById('rezension_textarea');
        const zeichenCounter = document.getElementById('zeichen_counter');

rezensionTextArea.addEventListener('input', () => {
         const zeichen = rezensionTextArea.value.length;
         zeichenCounter.textContent = `${zeichen}/800`;
        });
    )
}

export default Counter
```

Comment: You usually don't use `document.getElementById` when using React. You use states or refs instead. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835355/get-textarea-character-count-using-reactjs-with-help-of-usestate-hook

Comment: If you are new to react, I would suggest starting with some basic tutorials to get a hang of how it is used. Adding event listener and working directly with the DOM is the opposite of using react you could say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of textarea with react and useState hook.
useState return an array of getter and setter of a state.
the text value is stored in `text` and updated with `setState`.
textarea consume the state in handler with `value` and `onChange` parameter respectively.

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const MAX_TEXT_LENGTH = 800;
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  function handleTextAreaChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value.length <= MAX_TEXT_LENGTH) {
      setText(value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {`${text.length}/${MAX_TEXT_LENGTH}`}
      </div>
      <textarea rows={16} cols={64}
        onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
        value={text}>
      </textarea>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to react :)
That's not how it supposed to be, if you want to create a component with counter it should look like this:

```
function Counter() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

return (
    <div>
        {/*This will increment count by 1*/}
        <input type={"button"} value={"Click me"} onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)} />
        {/*This will decrement the count by 1*/}
        <input type={"button"} value={"Click me"} onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)} />
        {/*This will display the count*/}
        {count}
    </div>


)}
```

Just play along with it, but this is how you update the dom in React

Comment: It should be `()=> setCount(count=>count + 1)`. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Events in React are handled through the *onEvent* properties in the rendered JSX.
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
The `maxLength` attribute specifies the maximum count of a `<input>` & `<textarea>`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-maxlength

```
class Counter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {text: ''};
    }

    handleTextChange=(evt)=> {
        this.setState({ text: evt.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="App">
            <textarea value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleTextChange} maxLength="800" ></textarea>
            <p>count: {this.state.text.length}</p>
        </div>
    }
}
```